# I need to fail the build when a package imports from another package within the same project. How can I do so cleanly?

Tags: java, ant

For a variety of reasons (regardless of whether or not this is a wise idea) we have a project with several packages (say `one`, `two`, `three`) that are similar in structure. There is one additional `common` package.

I want the build to fail when something in each of those packages imports something that isn't in `common`, e.g. because you accidentally accepted the wrong import completion, or because Eclipse silently brought over the wrong imports while copy-pasting bug fixes from `one` into `two`.

What works is copying all the source files, except for each package, over to a temporary folder and attempting to build the result:

```
<target name="enforce-no-cross-imports">
    <phony-build without="one"/>
    <phony-build without="two"/>
    <phony-build without="three"/>
</target>

<macrodef name="phony-build">
    <attribute name="without" />
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Checking there are no cross imports to the @{without} package." />
        <mkdir dir="${java.io.tmpdir}/my-awesome-project/phony-build-@{without}/src" />
        <mkdir dir="${java.io.tmpdir}/my-awesome-project/phony-build-@{without}/bin" />
        <copy todir="${java.io.tmpdir}/my-awesome-project/phony-build-@{without}/src">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
                <exclude name="**/@{without}/"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <javac srcdir="${java.io.tmpdir}/my-awesome-project/phony-build-@{without}/src"
               destdir="${java.io.tmpdir}/my-awesome-project/phony-build-@{without}/bin"
               classpathref="classpath" encoding="UTF-8" nowarn="on"/>
        <delete dir="${java.io.tmpdir}/my-awesome-project" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

However, when the build *DOES* break, the error obviously occurs inside `${java.io.tmpdir}`.

```
enforce-no-cross-imports:
     [echo] Checking there are no cross imports to the one package.
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\my-awesome-project\phony-build-one\src
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\my-awesome-project\phony-build-one\bin
     [copy] Copying 47 files to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\my-awesome-project\phony-build-one\src
    [javac] Compiling 47 source files to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\my-awesome-project\phony-build-one\bin
    [javac] C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\my-awesome-project\phony-build-one\src\my\awesome\project\two\very\long\path\SomeController.java:43: package my.awesome.project.one.very.long.path.SomeConstantsClass does not exist
    [javac]     public static final String TEST = my.awesome.project.one.very.long.path.SomeConstantsClass.TEST;
```

As a result I can't click on the file name to jump directly to the issue. This adds way too much friction to the compilation process: it's bad enough that I'm effectively tripling the project build times.

What I thought I could do instead is *not* copy the files over and use the `excludes` attribute on the [`javac`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task instead:

> **excludes**: Comma- or space-separated list of files (may be specified using wildcard patterns) that must be excluded; no files (except default excludes) are excluded when omitted.

...except this does *not* cause the build to break. What happens is that javac will not compile the other packages, but it will still look at them for confirmation. Turning on `verbose` shows this log line:

```
    [javac] [checking my.awesome.project.one.very.long.path.SomeConstantsClass]
```

`includeDestClasses` seemed like another helpful flag, but setting it to `false` didn't help. `<compilerarg value="-implicit:none"/>` also was not helpful.

How can I tell `javac` that it really positively does need to exclude those files from the build, even if they are right there?

Alternatively, how can I take the output of javac and run find-replace on it so that the console output shows the correct path instead?

Comment: Yes, I _could_ somewhat enforce this at commit time with something *to the effect* of `if ! grep -n 'my\.awesome\.project\.(two|three)\.' **/one/*.java; then; exit 1; fi`, but (surprise surprise) our versioning system does not support commit hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `compilewithwalls` or `verifydesign` tasks of [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net), but the safest way to enforce separation like this is to isolate the modules into separate source directories and compile them independently.  You'd first build the common module, then build each of the other modules with the compiled classes of "common" on their classpaths but *not* the classes of any of the other modules.  This is the default approach when you're building with a higher level build tool like Maven.  If you have a directory structure like this:

- build.xml
- lib

  - library JAR files
- common

  - src
  - classes
- one

  - src
  - classes
- two

  - src
  - classes

then you could structure the build as

```
<macrodef name="compile-module">
  <attribute name="module" />
  <element name="depends" implicit="true" optional="true"/>
  <sequential>
    <javac srcDir="@{module}/src" destDir="@{module}/classes"
           encoding="UTF-8" nowarn="on">
      <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath" />
        <depends/>
      </classpath>
    </javac>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<compile-module name="common" />
<compile-module name="one">
  <pathelement location="common/classes" />
</compile-module>
<compile-module name="two">
  <pathelement location="common/classes" />
</compile-module>
<compile-module name="three">
  <pathelement location="common/classes" />
</compile-module>
```

You mention Eclipse in the question, so you'd need to do something similar there.  Eclipse allows the root of one project to be inside another, so you could create one main Eclipse project "myapp-common" pointed at your project root with just `common/src` as its source directory (and `common/classes` as the corresponding output directory), then create separate "myapp-one", "myapp-two" etc. projects rooted at the `one`, `two`, etc. folders, each depending on the "myapp-common" project.  That way you would never get Eclipse offering the "wrong" auto-completion, as project one simply cannot see project two or vice versa.